# Replace a TextBox based on DropDownList choice

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I choose an element from `DropDownList`, I want a `TexBox` to disappear and to be replaced by another one in the same exact position.

For example: I have a `DropDownList` filled with categories of SI equipments, Laptop, Desktop, Display etc. So when I choose Display, the RAM, CPU, HARD DISK textboxes must disappear and INCH `TextBox` should replace RAM TextBox.

This is my code:

```asp
<div>
    <label id="l1" class="label" >Numéro de série:</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="NumSerie"  CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="200px" />
    <label id="l8" class="label"> Systeme d'exploitation: </label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="SystemEx" CssClass="textbox" runat="server"  Height="32px" Width="200px" />
    <asp:Button class="NButton" ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="38px" Text="Ajouter" Width="140px" OnClick="Button1_Click"  />
</div>
<div>
    <label id="l2" class="label">Désignation:</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Designation" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="200px" />
    <label id="l9" class="label"> Processeur:</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Cpu" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="200px" />
    <asp:Button CssClass="NButton" ID="Button2" runat="server" Height="38px" Text="Modifier" Width="140px" />
</div>
<div>
    <label id="l3" class="label">
    <asp:TextBox ID="Marque" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="200px" />
    <label id="l10" class="label">Ram: </label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Ram" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="200px" />
    <asp:Button CssClass="NButton" ID="Button3" runat="server" Height="38px" Text="Supprimer" Width="140px" />
</div>
<div>
    <label id="l4" class="label">
    <br />
    Catégorie:</label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="IdCategorie" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="200px"/>
    <label id="l11" class="label"> Capacité destockage:</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="CapaciteSt" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="200px" />
    <asp:Button CssClass="NButton" ID="Button4" runat="server" Height="38px" Text="Rechercher" Width="140px" />
    </div>
<div>
    <label id="l5" class="label">
    <br />
    Code de fournisseur:</label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="CodeFour" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="200px" />
    <label id="l12" class="label"></label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Remise" class="textbox" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="200px" />
     <asp:Label ID="l15" runat="server" CssClass="label" Text="ID Equi:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="Rtextbox" ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="70px"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div>
    <label id="l6" class="label"></label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Prix" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="200px" />
    <label id="l13" class="label">Modele </label>
    <asp:TextBox Id="Modele" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="200px" />
</div>
<div>
    <label id="l7" class="label">  </label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="EtatGarantie" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="200px" />
    <label id="l14" class="label"></label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Pouces" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="200px" />
</div>
    <asp:Button CssClass="NButton" ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="&lt;&lt;" Width="55px"  />
```

Comment: Dude, seriously? Please format your code, this is ridiculous ... Need help? Read this: [Editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: you could use textbox visibility attribute to false on drop downlist selected index changed. Or else as you have div tag you could use `display:none` css style.

Comment: Sorry guys it's my first time here in the forum.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to replace the textbox. but it depends on if different selected items have different number of texboxes.

First set on your DropDownList `AutoPostBack="true"` then

You can simply change the placeholde runtime on `SelectedIndexChanged` of DropDownList like this

```
protected void ddlProducts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtDOB.Attributes.Add("placeholder", ddlProducts.SelectedItem.Text);
}
```

you can use same textbox for any item you selected.

Comment: mark it as answer if it solved your problem! @SaidBLZ